# WCF Not Deserializing. Why is my parameter NULL?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm trying to setup a web service that will accept predefined incoming SOAP/XML messages.  I have no control over the client code or the SOAP message sent.  I'm trying a simple example and am having a problem with it.  Let's say that this is the SOAP message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <CustomerRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
      <Customer>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      </Customer>
    </CustomerRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And my object with data contract:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Customer", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(Action="*")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    bool Customer(Customer customer);
}
```

When I send over the SOAP request I can view everything in fiddler and it looks to be fine.  But when it hits my code, the Customer object is null.  I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Here is also the raw request:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1.:3619/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IService1/Customer
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1.:3619
Content-Length: 339
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <CustomerRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
      <Customer>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      </Customer>
    </CustomerRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why not try it other way around? Build a WCF service that exposes this model and check what response it generates. Then fine tune this response until it matches with what you expect.

Comment: How are you defining your endpoint? Does the client send anything in the HTTP headers as well (such as the `SOAPAction` header)?

Comment: I don't have any control of the SOAP that is incoming.  It may be the endpoint.  I'm just using the default build endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any mention of `CustomerRequest` in your interface or service implementation. I think the SOAP request should be sending a `Customer` rather than `CustomerRequest`. You can verify this by using SOAPUI and generating a sample request based on your WSDL. Will tell you what the request should *actually* look like.

Comment: I don't have any control of the incoming SOAP.  But, to test what you are saying I did remove the Customer Request and just used Customer.  No luck.

Comment: Understood. What I think you need to do is to change your contract so that it matches what the client would expect. Looking at the soap message you've shown, the client is expecting to see a `[MessageContract]` called `CustomerRequest` a `[MessageBodyMember]` called `Body` containing a `DataContract` called `Customer`. Your service implementation should then take a `CustomerRequest` as it's input. I strongly recommend you use SoapUI. It'll help you to debug manipulating your contract so that it exhibits the interface you need for the client to be able to call your service successfully.

Comment: I removed (Action="*") from my OperationContract and used the WCF Test Client to view the request and was able to get it working.  Also, I had to set the XMLSerializerFormat to [XmlSerializerFormat(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use=OperationFormatUse.Literal)]

Comment: _[XmlSerializerFormat(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use=OperationFormatUse.Literal)]_ - worked just right for me.